# Need help understanding boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have been evaluating boolean expressions, in one expression I arrived at a point where I had to evaluate ('b'c + bc) which I failed to do, the steps in the answer show that it is simplified as '(b XOR c), I need help understanding how does this ('b'c + bc) evaluates to '(b XOR c)?

Comment: how to convert or simplify ('b'c + bc) to '(b XOR c), which rule or law am I supposed to apply?

Comment: Draw truth tables for each step in turn; `'b'c`, `bc` and `('b'c + bc)`.  Then do `b XOR c` and finally `'(b XOR c)`.  Hopefully you should see the result you need.

Comment: XOR can be thought as "are different", here you need "are equal"...

Comment: @Izukanji, if the answers were useful, please upvote them and mark one as 'accepted'.  On the other hand, if you need further help, please indicate this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`bc` is true when `b` and `c` are both true.
`'b'c` is true when `b` and `c` are both false.
So the sum of these is true when `a` and `b` are both true or both false.

`b XOR c` is true when `b` is true and `c` is false or vice versa.
Alternatively, `b XOR c` is false when `a` and `b` are both true or both false.

Hopefully you can therefore see that `'(b XOR c)` is true when `a` and `b` are both true or both false.

QED.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that *b XOR c* is represented by *(b+c)('b+'c)*, hence

*'(b XOR c)* = *'((b+c)('b+'c))* = *'(b+c)+'('b+'c)* = *'b'c+bc*

Comment: FWIW, the moves from step 2 to step 3, and from 3 to 4 above are using [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)